# How to set a custom text highlighting colour

Tags: gnome, themes, configuration, gui, customization

If you use the Adwaita theme you get Blue as the highlighting colour, for Numix you get Red/Orange (not sure exactly which), I have Numix, and like it, but I would like to change the highlighting colour (but not theme) to Green for a change, how can this be achieved? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color code is `#d64937`

```
find "/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/gtk-3.0" -type f -name '*.css' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'd64937'
```

therefore you have to change two files:

```
sudo nano "/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/gtk-3.0/gtk-dark.css"
sudo nano "/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/gtk-3.0/gtk.css"
```

Search for

```
@define-color selected_bg_color #d64937;
```

And replace with

```
@define-color selected_bg_color #4A90D9;
```

Restart GNOME via <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> any type `r` **isn't enough**, logout and re-login.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is no longer true since GTK 3.18+ because GNOME decided that CSS needed to be incredibly complicated so they compiled it into a custom binary called "gresource". GNOME makes silly decisions way too much.