# Where has the gnome terminal GTK3 style configuration moved to in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, gtk3

In Ubuntu 14.04, I could style the appearance of the gnome terminal and its tabs by creating a file

```
/home/$user/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

and putting CSS code into it e.g.

```
    TerminalWindow .notebook tab.top:active{
      padding: 0;
      border-image: none;
      background-color: #555;
    }
    [...]
```

Now on Ubuntu 16.04 this has no affect on the appearance of gnome terminal.
How can I modify gnome terminal's appearance on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Could you please mention the name of the gtk3 theme you're using? If you've tried different gtk3 themes, which are those? The reason I'm asking is hinted at here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/765909/tweaking-newer-gtk3-themes

Comment: BTW, there are quite a few differences in "gtk3" when moving from 14.04 (gtk 3.10) to 16.04 (gtk 3.18).

Comment: @DKBose this is the default theme. I tried installing a theme once in the last 6 years,  and within a few hours - the system completely locked up, no tty nothing. Which is quite amazing that changing some icons and cosmetic items could cause catastrophic system failure. I would like to think it wasn't the theme, but I dont want to take the risk again!

Comment: @DKBose if you are intested the theme I installed which *allegedly* broke my system was [numix GTK](https://numixproject.org/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=52) it seems from you other question  you have tried it too?

Comment: IMO, you maybe safest with `adwaita`. It comes pre-packed with any GNOME-distro. By default theme, I'm guessing Ambiance. Ambiance in 16.04 is still old-school and so you should be able to edit things simply unlike with the Numix issue I described. If you can't, that simply means that the GNOME devs have hard-coded something :(

Comment: Have you tried editing `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css` instead of `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`? The latter basically points to `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` which has `@import url("apps/gnome-terminal.css");` near the end of the file.

Comment: @DKBose . you are right that my theme is "ambiance". the file I am used to editing on 14.04 was in my home dir `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` changes to this file used to take effect immediately on any new instances of gnome terminal (existing windows would be unaffected). I just tried editing the files you mentioned and it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
/* gnome-terminal */
@define-color terminal_bg #300a24;

TerminalScreen {
    -TerminalScreen-background-darkness: 0.95;
    background-color: @terminal_bg;
    color: #fff;
}

TerminalScreenContainer .scrollbar:hover:not(.slider),
TerminalScreenContainer .scrollbar.dragging:not(.slider) {
    background-color: alpha(@scrollbar_track_color, 0.4);
}

/* Since .hovering class is not working here, we always
 use the same radius */
TerminalScreenContainer .scrollbar.slider.hovering,
TerminalScreenContainer .scrollbar.slider.dragging {
    border-radius: 1px;
}

TerminalScreenContainer .scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

The code I added is at the bottom. The file I edited is `~/.themes/ORIG-Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css`.

Notes:

- I just copied over the *Ambiance* folder from `/usr/share/themes` and renamed it so that I don't need to use elevated privileges while editing the file.
- I found that using `#555` made it difficult to see the text in the tab.
- I also changed the `selected_fg_color` to be sure of which theme is which and that's why the scrollbar isn't orange ;)

[image: gnome-terminal]

Comment: oh wow, nice work! I am currently working on setting gnome terminal preferences through gnome 3's gsettings program. once finjshed Ill try your code amd let you know how it went!

Comment: I've tried the things you've shown and its not doing anything, Im just wondering how you applied these changes? By adding this whole folder structure have you essentially created a new theme? If so does that mean you need to apply the theme in the same way you would apply e.g. a theme like `Numix` by using a tweak tool and and select the new theme `ORIG-Ambiance` from drop down menu and restart application, gnome , or user session?

Comment: I think you can do exactly what I did _but_ with `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css`. That way, you won't have the hassle of needing to switch themes. Of course, you'll need to use `sudo nano` or whatever you use to edit system files. And a back-up would be a good idea. I use the Openbox session of Lubuntu and it doesn't require me to install special tools to change themes. I just have a list of themes in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` with all except one commented out. Changing *user-level* themes is then just a matter of editing that file.

Comment: For system-wide changes, the corresponding file is in `/etc/gtk-3.0/`.

Comment: thanks. - upvote - even if it doesnt directly fix the problem its still got good info on how to modify GTK. I will have a look and let you know if it works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Logging out/closing all my programs and logging back in applied the theming after all.
The GTK API reference for [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkCssProvider.html) (the unstable dev version - I cant find the equivalent sections for  stable) explains/confirms how GTK will read CSS code for a theme on startup:

> An application can cause GTK+ to parse a specific CSS style sheet by calling gtk_css_provider_load_from_file() and adding the provider with gtk_style_context_add_provider() or gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen().
>   In addition, certain files will be read when GTK+ is initialized. First, the file $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/gtk.css is loaded if it exists.
>   Then, GTK+ tries to load $HOME/.themes/theme-name/gtk-3.0/gtk.css, falling back to datadir/share/themes/theme-name/gtk-3.0/gtk.css, where theme-name is the name of the current theme (see the "gtk-theme-name" setting) and datadir is the prefix configured when GTK+ was compiled, unless overridden by the GTK_DATA_PREFIX environment variable.

Previous experience suggested gnome-terminal all you needed to do was close all gnome-terminal tabs and windows to make new theming take effect.
As per the docs, maybe GTK  needed to go through its initialisation, or there may have been a `gnome-terminal` process still running, requiring me to logout and back in.