# 20.04: How do you view a theme's gtk.css (resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-light/3.0/gtk.css)?

Tags: gnome, themes, 20.04

A theme's gtk.css (`/usr/share/themes/Yaru-light/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`) used to (18.04) contain the full css, now (20.04) it's just `@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-light/3.0/gtk.css");`. So how do you view it?

Comment: Related, if not an exact duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/765909/248158

Comment: Why was my answer to use "gresource" command deleted? It was a valid answer, as I have used this command exactly for this - view the content of .css file bundled inside the .gresource file. The command is pretty much self-explanatory if you just run it without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The actual CSS resources appear to now be stored in .gresource files. You can use the `gresource` command to list and extract resources in these files. For example, on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, to extract the CSS for the Yaru-blue theme, I use:

```
$ gresource extract /usr/share/themes/Yaru-blue/gtk-3.0/gtk.gresource /com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-blue/3.0/gtk.css
```